# Android: Text size not changing

Tags: android, database, sqlite, text-size

I'm doing a quiz using SQLite database and the questions and answers i pull from the database dont seem to change to the size i set in the XML file. I have narrowed it down to the stuff pulled from the database so i'm wondering why its only that.  here is all the classes involved

DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
// tasks table name
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";

private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
dbase=db;
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
+ " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
+KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sql);
addQuestions();

//db.close();
}

private void addQuestions()
{
    Question q1=new Question("8 X 2 " + "=","16", "20", "18", "16");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("8 X 3  " +    "=", "20", "24", "26", "24");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("8 X 4 " + " =","30", "35","32","32");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("8 X 5 " + " = ", "40", "38", "41","40");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("8 X 6 " +" =","45","48","50","48");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6=new Question("8 X 7 " +" =","55","56","58","56");
    this.addQuestion(q6);
    Question q7=new Question("8 X 8 " +" =","64","68","60","64");
    this.addQuestion(q7);
    Question q8=new Question("8 X 9 " +" =","75","72","70","72");
    this.addQuestion(q8);
    Question q9=new Question("8 X 10 " +" =","81","89","80","80");
    this.addQuestion(q9);
    Question q10=new Question("8 X [  ]  " +" = 8","1","9","5","1");
    this.addQuestion(q10);
    Question q11=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 24","5","3","6","3");
    this.addQuestion(q11);
    Question q12=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 40","6","9","5","5");
    this.addQuestion(q12);
    Question q13=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 56","7","8","9","7");
    this.addQuestion(q13);
    Question q14=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 80","7","10","9","10");
    this.addQuestion(q14);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
// Drop older table if existed
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
// Create tables again
onCreate(db);
}
// Adding new question
public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
//SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
// Inserting Row
dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
}
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
Question quest = new Question();
quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
quesList.add(quest);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
// return quest list
return quesList;
}

public int rowcount()
{
int row=0;
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
row=cursor.getCount();
return row;
}
}
```

Exercise.java

```
public class Exercise1 extends Activity
{
List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
Button rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exercise1);
    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    //butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    rda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String s = currentQ.getANSWER();
            Log.d("Exercise", s);

            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(rda.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                if(qid<4)
                {
                        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                        setQuestionView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Exercise1.this, Tables2.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.d("Exercise", "not working ");
            }
        }


        });
    rdb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("Exercise", "Button B pressed");
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(rdb.getText()))
            {
                score++;

                if(qid<4)
                {
                        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                        setQuestionView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Exercise1.this, Tables2.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.d("Exercise", "not working");
            }
        }


        });
    rdc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.d("Exercise", "Button C pressed");
            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(rdc.getText()))
            {
                score++;
                Log.d("Exercise", "Wrong Answer");

                if(qid<4)
                {
                        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                        setQuestionView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Exercise1.this, Tables2.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Exercise", "not workingr");
            }
        }


        });
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++;
}

}
```

exercise.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".QuizActivity"
android:background="@drawable/exercise" >
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_height="200sp"
               android:text="Large Text"
                       android:textSize="50sp"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
                   android:id="@+id/radio0"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:checked="true"
                   android:text="RadioButton" />
    <Button
                   android:id="@+id/radio1"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="RadioButton" />
    <Button
                   android:id="@+id/radio2"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="RadioButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

i would assume its somewhere in here as to why my text size is not changing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you are expecting the text size to change here.

Comment: will it not change size if i pull it from a database?

Comment: Where are you trying to set the size outside of your layout?

Comment: i'm not i only setting the size within the Textview. no matter how big i make the text within the TextView it stays the same size

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I'm clearly not understanding your true issue. Are you having an issue with font size, with the physical size of the view, or something else entirely?

Comment: the font size. when i set the "android:textsize"50sp"" there is not change in the fontsize when i run the app.

Comment: Ok, the issue is you are also setting `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` which will override your font size. Remove that and it should respect the font size you set in the layout.

Comment: ok so i took that out and the fontsize still did not change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53853/discussion-between-dcharms-and-darren-murtagh)